# While using Pyrocms how do I link to an individual post?

Tags: pyrocms

How do I link to an individual post while loading a specific layout? I currently have a blog layout in which I am loading all blog posts. From here I want to be able to click on an individual post that will load up just that post with a specific layout. However right now everytime i click on a post it loads up the same layout.

Comment: Please show how you are calling the data. Is it a plugin? Are you doing this in PHP? Are you summoning the information through the mystic chant of MugRa? I can't help if you are vague. :)

Answer (score 1):

To edit the post "view" layout, copy the file /system/cms/modules/blog/views/view.php into addons/shared_addons/themes//views/modules/blog/ and edit this layout to make it what you want. Is this what your asking?